# Calculate slope - just with angle

Tags: math, formula, angle

I want to calculate the slope in %
for example i just have the angle:
(maybe in PHP or Javascript)
    slope(22.5) //50%

```
0=0%
22.5=50%
45=100%
67,5=50%
90=0%
112,5=50%
135=100%
180=0
202,5=50%
225=100%
270=0
```

Comment: your example values don't seem to make any sense. The slope of a line at 67.5 degrees is 2.41. The percentage (grade) is almost 300 at 67.5 (and for 22.5 is more like 43). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_(slope)

Comment: @Garr, it only really makes sense if you consider the result to be the angular distance between the given angle and the nearest quadrant boundary, expressed as a percentage of the maximum possible. So not so much a slope as the title implies. Of course, that's assuming the test data is correct rather than the title.

Comment: Any particular programming language? It is easier to give answers you can use directly if you specify.  Moreover I suggest you clarify the question. It appears you want the slope with respect to the nearest quadrant.

Comment: The use of % to express a gradient is used for example on European road signs; it indicates the ratio of ascent over horizontal distance travelled.  In that case however only one octant is considered, so it is not clear what the application in this case might be.

Comment: dazza, can you please clarify the question. The answer you've accepted doesn't match the expected results you gave. For example 22.5 will give 41-ish rather than 50. If the accepted answer *is* what you wanted (and it may have just been a miscommunication), you should change your expected results in the question, otherwise the question is not much good for others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using similar reasoning as paxdiablo I came up with this one-liner

```
slope = 100*abs(((angle+45) mod 90)-45)/45;
```

You should be able to see the plot here: [go to wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+100*abs%28%28%28x%2B45%29+mod+90%29-45%29%2F45+from+x%3D0+to+360)

Comment: That is *truly* hideous :-) But, probably more important, it doesn't actually give the values that were requested. Plug 22.5 into that and you get about 41, *not* 50. So either the OP has screwed up their question or they haven't realised the error.

Comment: @paxidiablo That's right! After rereading the question it became obvious that this function can't contain any nonlinear terms. The concept of expressing a slope in percentages leaves some room for interpretation but of course the question stated it clearly. My mistake. I've already corrected my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It appears based on your data that, in *each* quadrant, you linearly rise from 0 to 100% in the first 45 degrees and drop back down to 0% in the second 45 degrees.

So, you can map all angles into the first quadrant, `0 <= angle < 90`, with:

```
angle = angle % 90
```

Then if it's in the second half of that quadrant, transform it with a rotation around the 45 degree line with:

```
if angle >= 45:
    angle = 90 - angle
```

Now you have an angle `0 <= angle < 45` that's effectively the "distance" from the nearest quadrant boundary, and you can do:

```
percent = angle * 100 / 45
```

to get that expressed as a percentage.

So, in short:

```
angle = angle % 90
if angle >= 45:
    angle = 90 - angle
percent = angle * 100 / 45
```

As proof of concept, here's some Python code that shows it in action:

```
for i in range (361):
    angle = i % 90
    if angle >= 45:
        angle = 90 - angle
    percent = angle * 100 // 45
    print("%d -> %d" % (i, percent))
```

along with the abridged output:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 6
::
43 -> 95
44 -> 97
45 -> 100
46 -> 97
47 -> 95
48 -> 93
49 -> 91
::
87 -> 6
88 -> 4
89 -> 2
90 -> 0
91 -> 2
92 -> 4
93 -> 6
::
352 -> 17
353 -> 15
354 -> 13
355 -> 11
356 -> 8
357 -> 6
358 -> 4
359 -> 2
360 -> 0
```

Comment: Thankss !! seems to work well in pyton...but whats the exactly formula for this: " angle = i % 90 "  ??

Comment: @dazzafact, it's the modulo operator, the remainder you get when you divide a number by something. For positive numbers, `i = i % 90` is the same as `while i >= 90: i = i - 90`.

Answer (score -1):

slope=abs(tan(angle))*100

¿Is this what you wanted?

Comment: (Make sure your `tan` function takes degrees rather than radians, or convert to radians first)

Comment: Yes, I assumed from the request he wanted to use degrees.

Comment: this doesn't seem to give answers that match the desired results. The desired results don't look much like a slope, either.

Comment: You have missed the point made by Sneftel; in most programming languages or libraries, the trig functions take arguments in radians not degrees. The question does indeed use degrees, in which case you'd need `tan(angle/180*PI)`.

Comment: @Clifford, you are right, but it doesn't say anything about programming laguages. Anyway, your note is helpful.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, just for reference: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog482spring2/c7_p10.html How does it not match the desired results?

Comment: @macl - look at the OP examples. At 22.5 your solution gives the grade, 41%. But OP wants 50%. At 67.5 OP wants 50% and yours gives 241.

Comment: Apart from that, this does not give the result the OP requires. For example the tangent of 90 degrees is infinite. In his question, he changes the reference point to the nearest quadrant.

Comment: I'm not sure tangents are the way to go here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169871/why-is-the-tangent-of-22-5-degrees-not-1-2

Comment: WTH? Check out https://www.google.com.au/search?q=tangent+90+degrees - I'm pretty certain the `1e16` is about the same distance from infinite as zero is :-) Actually, never mind, math.se has the answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536144/why-does-the-google-calculator-give-tan-90-degrees-1-6331779e16. Isn't SE wonderful?

Comment: @macl : No he did not specify a language, which was rather Sneftel's point. I think the comment was aimed at the reader rather than a criticism of your solution.